# Placement of absolutely positioned elements

Tags: html, css

According to my understanding, absolutely positioned elements are only affected by it's nearest ancestor which has a position of relative or fixed.

When I was messing around with scrolling tables, there seems to be an odd case where div elements inside a table header take into the account of it's parent `th` element, which is not relatively positioned. Why is this the case?

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3vGwP/

css:

```
/* table borders */

.scrollArea table tr th:first-child .th-inner {
  border-left: none;
}
.scrollArea table tbody tr td {
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  border-right: 0px;
  border-bottom: 0px;
}

/* scrollable table */

.scrollableContainer {
  height: 283px;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 22px;
  width: 756px;
}

.scrollableContainer .headerSpacer {
  border: 1px solid #d5d5d5;
  border-bottom-color: #bbb;
  position: absolute;
  height: 21px;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.scrollArea {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  border: 1px solid #d5d5d5;
}

.scrollArea table {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  border: none;
  border-collapse: separate;
}

.scrollArea table th {
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
}

/* using absolute positions means the original table header has no content, hence is collapsed */

.scrollArea table .th-inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 21px;
  border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="scrollableContainer">
  <div class="headerSpacer"></div>
  <div class="scrollArea">
    <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
      <thead class="fixedHeader">
        <tr>
          <th>
            <div class="th-inner">Header 1</div>
          </th>
          <th>
            <div class="th-inner">Header 2</div>
          </th>
          <th>
            <div class="th-inner">Header 3</div>
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody class="scrollContent">
        <tr>
          <td>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
          <td>bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb</td>
          <td>cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc</td>
          ...
```

Comment: Are you seeing the issue in Firefox only, as indicated by @clami219's answer?

Comment: I've tested it on chrome (36 canary) & firefox (29), both give the same thing, quite amazing if the same bug exists on completely different platforms.

Comment: Moreso since the [FF bug ticket](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=35168) indicates that Chrome has been working just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue. [Here](http://davidwalsh.name/table-cell-position-absolute) is explained a solution that could work for you.

Here is a brief example of how it would apply to your case:

```
...
<th>
    <div style="position:relative; overflow: auto; height: 100%;">
        <div class="th-inner">Header 1</div>
    </div>
</th>
...
```

Comment: Just to clarify, according to the blogpost, this is a bug thats present on *most* of the major browsers?

Comment: @simonzack The blog post indicates that it is a FF-only bug: `Chrome?  Check.  Internet Explorer?  Check.  Firefox?  Ugh, FML.`. This raises the question of whether you're seeing the same bug.